# How to watermark and display user generated html in .NET

Tags: html, .net, webbrowser-control

I need to come up with a way to watermark user generated HTML and display it to the user.

I played around with modifying the HTML by setting a background image, but the solution didn't work if the any html element contained a background color or image.

So I thought it would be easier to display the HTML in a web browser control and watermark the control. Boy was I wrong.

I tried creating a user control and derive from WebBrowser and overwrite the paint method. That didn't work.

Next idea was to just draw on top of a webbrowser control.

here's what I've come up with. In this example I slapped a label, webbrowser control and two picture boxes on a form. I create the image and set it to both picture boxes. I put one picture box over the label and the other over the watermark.

The picturebox over the label displayed as I expected, but the picturebox over the webbrowser control did not.

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string WatermarkText = "Confidential";
    Font WatermarkFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 24, FontStyle.Bold);
    int WatermarkAngle = 45;
    Color WatermarkColor = Color.PaleTurquoise;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AllowTransparency = true;

        label1.AutoSize = false;
        label1.Text = "Test Text";
        label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        var img = creategraphics(WatermarkText);

        label1.Size = pictureBox2.Size = pictureBox1.Size = img.Size;

        label1.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);

        webBrowser1.Controls.Add(pictureBox2);
        pictureBox2.Image = img;
        pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        pictureBox2.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }

    Image creategraphics(string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)) return null;

        var size = getWatermarkSize(text, WatermarkAngle, WatermarkFont, out double hypotenuse);
        var img = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        var brush = new SolidBrush(WatermarkColor);
        var stringFormat = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
        g.RotateTransform((float)-WatermarkAngle);
        g.DrawString(text, WatermarkFont, brush, new Point(0, (int)hypotenuse / 2), stringFormat);
        return img;
    }

    private static Size getWatermarkSize(string text, int angle, Font font, out double hypotenuse)
    {
        if (angle > 90) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("angle");

        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1))
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            var size = graphics.MeasureString(text, font);
            hypotenuse = size.Width + size.Height;
            double radians = (angle / 180.0) * Math.PI;
            var width = (Math.Cos(radians) * size.Width) + (Math.Sin(radians) * size.Height);
            var height = (Math.Cos(radians) * size.Height) + (Math.Sin(radians) * size.Width);
            return new Size((int)width, (int)height);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get

[image]